# How to access nested maps ref in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I have a react-native-maps component nested multiple levels down. How do I access the map.animateToRegion function from the parent container?

```
class Parent extends Component{
  animateToRegion = () => {
    /*Need some way to call the mapview ref*/
  }
  return(
    <Child />
  )
}
```

```
class Child extends Component{
  return(
    <MapView ref={map => this.map = map}>
    </MapView>
  )
}
```

Comment: Your `Child` component that just forward their ref with `React.forwardRef`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
class Parent extends Component{
  animateToRegion = () => {
     this.map.animateToRegion(yourRegionObj, 100);
  }
  return(
    <Child
       mapRef={map => this.map = map}
    />
  )
}
```

```
class Child extends Component{
  return(
    <MapView ref={this.props.mapRef}>
    </MapView>
  )
}
```